# Exclude a column in History table

Tags: sql-server

I have a temporal table for my employee as shown below. But the problem is that the `[data]` column which is of type `xml` makes the history table grow so fast and users are running out of space.

To solve this I need a temporal table by excluding the `data` column which means I am not going to have data column in my temporal table; is that possible?

I do not care on what changes in the `data` xml at this point.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(
      [EmployeeID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
      , [Name] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
      , [Position] varchar(100) NOT NULL
      , [Department] varchar(100) NOT NULL
      , [Data]  [xml] NOT NULL
      , [ValidFrom] datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
      , [ValidTo] datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
      , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)
)
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeeHistory));
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. Temporal tables are all or nothing.

Comment: If you don't want the XML to be temporal, store it in a different table (that isn't temporal).

Comment: I can't because that is old table that have a lot of dependencies and it will cost me a lot of code changes which is not preferred at this point.

Comment: That's why views are a thing though. You can even allow them to be treated as regular tables for modification purposes by defining triggers. Even temporal logic (`FOR SYSTEM_TIME OF`) can be forwarded transparently through a view. The only complication would be drawing up a plan for data migration/table renaming with minimal downtime.

Comment: Well you're going to need a system redesign somewhere, if you don't want `data` to not be temporal. I would, personally, move the data from the `data` column to a new table (linked by `EmployeeID`) and then create a `VIEW`, which has `INSTEAD OF` triggers.